# Using "&" in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to optimize the following using SASS:

```
.title {
  font-family: Arial;
}

h1.title {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h2.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I tried

```
.title {
  font-family: Arial;

  h1.& {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  h2.& {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

which gives me `Invalid CSS after "  h1.": expected class name, was "& {"` syntax error, since "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ampersand first:

```
.title {
    font-family: arial;

    &h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```